# How would you assign read-only permissions to run ls -l /proc/{pid}/fd for processes you don't own using SELinux in Android

Tags: permissions, security, android, selinux, proc

I am developing an application on Android as a non-root user. 
However, I need read access to all the `/proc/{pid}/fd` files so as to check the inode numbers from the symlink under `fd`.

How do I do that using SELinux policy?